TypeError with Firebase Functions Auth Trigger in v6.1.0
I'm trying to set up a Firebase Auth trigger for user deletion using Firebase Functions v6.1.0, but I'm getting a TypeError. Here's my minimal reproduction case:
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const { getFirestore } = require('firebase-admin/firestore');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.registerUser = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    
});

exports.deleteUser = functions.auth.user().onDelete(async () => { // <<<< ERROR
    
});

This produces the error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'user')
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/thierry/Documents/firebase-app/functions/index.js:16:37)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1546:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1691:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1317:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1127:12)
    at TracingChannel.traceSync (node:diagnostics_channel:315:14)
    at wrapModuleLoad (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:217:24)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1339:12)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:135:16)
    at loadModule (/Users/thierry/Documents/firebase-app/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/runtime/loader.js:40:16)

Environment:
firebase-functions: 6.1.0
firebase-admin: 12.7.0
Node.js: 22
I've tried various syntaxes including:
functions.auth.user().beforeDelete
functions.identity.beforeUserDeleted
functions.auth.userDeleted().onEvent
But none of them work. According to the Firebase documentation, this should be the correct syntax.
How can I properly set up an Auth trigger for user deletion in Firebase Functions v6.1.0?
Thanks!

As per the Firebase documentations on Trigger a function on user deletion it expects a user variable to be used within the callback function
Which is why you are getting undefined for user.
exports.deleteUser = functions.auth.user().onDelete(async (user) => {
  // ...                                                     
});


Reference : auth.UserBuilder.onDelete()


Unfortunately I am getting the same error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'user')
at Object.

Using this minimal script:
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
exports.deleteUser = functions.auth.user().onDelete(async (user) => {
});

You exemple is for gen 1st API right?

@thierryb Yes I'm using 1st gen API. Did you initialize it using firebase init functions or firebase init then choose JavaScript as a function language ? Right ?
Could you also try the same by using typescript since these errors are better caught in typescript.

Also consider importing firebase-functions as firebase-functions/v1

As stated in the Auth triggers documentation, firebase functions Gen 2 do not have Auth triggers. They were replaced by identity triggers.
You have 2 options to address this:

Import gen 1 functions as const functions = require('firebase-functions/v1');
Use the beforeUserCreated trigger. See documentation for more details.

